# Jquery differences 1.4.2 and 1.8.3 ?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to implement html5advent calendar to my site . The calendar is prepared by using `jquery-min 1.4.2`. In my site I have many plugins of jquery ui so I want to use a `jquery-min 1.8.3`.

The link that I am working is `<a href="01">`.When I click link.The links works without problems in Firefox. But the chromium/chrome  links does not work and console throws  me `" Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href=#day.1] "`

The source of error codes are the lines below

```
 $.each(PINT.calendarInfo, function() {
                PINT_calendarActivateDay($('a[href=#day' + this.toString() + ']'), false);
            });
```

If I use 1.4.2 calendar works without problems but other plugins stop working. 
What changes can be made to make it work?

Comment: Can you show the code in `PINT_calendarActivateDay`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote the attribute value.

```
$.each(PINT.calendarInfo, function() {
    PINT_calendarActivateDay($('a[href="#day' + this.toString() + '"]'), false);
});
```

Comment: hey ThiefMaster thanks a lot.now only this is left : Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://izmirkukla.dev/showings".